# Dynamic gremlin traversal construction

Tags: gremlin

I'm migrating from the deprecated `gremlin-javascript` to the new Tinkerpop `gremlin`.

`gremlin-javascript` supported an `execute` method that would take an arbitrary string as a traversal. We could dynamically create and pass this string, such as chaining an arbitrary number of `property` traversals on a vertex.

Is there a way to dynamically build traversals in the `gremlin` js client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all language variants of Gremlin (Java, JS, Python, etc), you write Gremlin by constructing a `Traversal` object. You have a `g` which is a `GraphTraversalSource` which spawns those `Traversal` objects and thus:

```
var t = g.V().values('names');
```

does not yield a result (i.e. a list of "name" values) in `t` but a `Traversal` object. To get the result you need to iterate the traversal as for example:

```
t.toList().then(names => console.log(names));
```

So, if you have a `Traversal` object that is not yet iterated you can continue to add to it:

```
var t = g.V().values('names');
t = t.limit(1);
t.next().then(...)
```

Comment: How would you dynamically build an 'or' clause, where the number of predicates is dynamic? For instance, if I want to execute something like this: g.V().or(__.has('concept_id', 'G1200000000'), __.has('concept_id', 'G1200000099'))

Comment: in that specific case, just make a list of "concept_id" and give it to `g.V().has('concept_id', within(conceptIds))`. if you can't do that for some reason and must construct an `or()` then note that this step is varargs so you can just pass it an array of traversals of arbitrary size and it should work.